# pandas DataFrame.style.render when some strings have UTF-8 characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, pandas-styles

When using `dataframe.style`, accented characters are shown correctly on Jupyter:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([['Madrid', 'León']], index=['Spain'], columns=['BigCity', 'SmallCity'])
df.style    
        BigCity SmallCity
Spain   Madrid  León
```

However, if we use the `style.render()` method to obtain the HTML and write it to a file, the accented characters are not encoded correctly:

```
df.style.render()
'<style  type="text/css" >\n</style>  \n<table id="T_a3788466_eb00_11e8_8a82_88e9fe638ee6" > \n<thead>    <tr> \n        <th class="blank level0" ></th> \n        <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >BigCity</th> \n        <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >SmallCity</th> \n    </tr></thead> \n<tbody>    <tr> \n        <th id="T_a3788466_eb00_11e8_8a82_88e9fe638ee6level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >Spain</th> \n        <td id="T_a3788466_eb00_11e8_8a82_88e9fe638ee6row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >Madrid</td> \n        <td id="T_a3788466_eb00_11e8_8a82_88e9fe638ee6row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >León</td> \n    </tr></tbody> \n</table> '
```

And of course that doesn't work. This is what the browser shows:

---

[image]

---

How can this be corrected?

Comment: I think its a problem with HTML render rather than pandas creating an issue. I checked your code at my end, it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is not an HTML or Pandas problem exactly, but a character set problem.  See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Your "Latin small latin o with acute" is 0xC3 0xB3 in UTF-8.  The first byte is therefore 195 and the second is 179.  And behold at the link above, 195 is "Latin capital letter A with tilde," while 179 is "superscript three."  That's why you see Ã³.

So Pandas is producing correct UTF-8 HTML, but nobody is telling the browser.  You can either explicitly set the HTML charset to UTF-8, or you can explicitly set the HTML version to 5 (which is supposed to default to UTF-8, though there may be browser-specific quirks).

Another way to fix it might be to take the output from Pandas and call `.encode('ISO-8859-1')` to convert it before writing to a file.  That will write ó as 243, which should work without changing the HTML headers.  This will definitely not work correctly if you ever have a document containing characters not in ISO-8859-1, whereas keeping it in UTF-8 would support every character.

Comment: Thank you @John. My profile is what you may call citizen data scientist with scant knowledge about character sets. Admittedly, I do not know what is ISO-8859-1, or how to set the HTML version in a browser.  

The browsers used are Safari 12.0.1 and Firefox 63.0.3. 

Anyway, your solution works for latin characters, but I also have Chinese characters: 

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 280042-280057: ordinal not in range(256)`

Is there an approach that abstracts this problem? Or must I inevitably make the time investment to learn all this?

Comment: For Chinese characters you cannot encode to latin-1, you have to either set your HTML document to HTML5 or HTML charset to UTF-8.  Either of these can be done with HTML headers, for which there's plenty of documentation online.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to my own question is as simple as prepending the output from the render() method with a header like this:

```
outputHTML = '<meta charset="UTF-8">'+df.style.render()
```

FWIW I still do not understand why the render() method doesn't do this automatically. There may be plenty of documentation online as John points out, but I have not been able to find an explanation.